# Какой движок выбрать для доски объявлений?

Tags: framework, php, cms

Добрый день всем.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, движок или cms с компонентами или фрэймворк, который наиболее подходит (удобен) для реализации доски объявлений такой, как вот [эта](http://www.leboncoin.fr/).

Спасибо за ответы...

Comment: За каждое мнение поставлю +1

Comment: А за правильный ответ галочку)

Comment: Подожду ещё ответов )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть идея и надо что то не шаблонное, то советую MVC фреймворки - Yii, CodeIgniter, ZF. Если подойдет шаблонное - поддержу [@chambo](/users/3333/chambo)

Comment: Ok, спасибо за ваше мнение..

Answer (score 2):

Привет! На Joomle удобно реализовать доску объявлений! Качаешь к Joomle компонент доска объявлений! Попробуй, это интересно! Вот, например, [сылка на компонент](http://www.dotfun.ru/seo-joomla-poiskovaya-optimizatsciya-sayita/free-board-almond-classifieds-for-joomla.html).

Comment: Можно где-то посмотреть как он работает?

Comment: Надо это искать! Легче всего скачать joomlu и поставить этот компонент!

Comment: Посмотреть как оно будет выглядеть:
[Almond Classifieds Scripts: Editions, Demos](http://www.almondsoft.com/alcl.html)<br>
Только там, похоже, что не будет поиска (полнотекстового) см. [Almond Classifieds Component for Joomla](http://www.almondsoft.com/jm/index.php?option=com_aclsfgpl)

Answer (score 1):

Для практически любых интернет-задач поставленных для сайта отлично подходит EBIZ CMS. Это интернет-магазин с возможностью продажи по WebMoney или любому другому интернет-сервису платежей, со своим мощным форумом любой глубины вложенности тем, своей социальной сетью для создания сообщества вокруг продаваемых Вами товаров и пр. и т.д. и т.п.)) Вы обязательно найдёте в нём то что ищете здесь!